# find centre using optim()

Tags: r, optimization

I have some coordinates and I wanted to find the centre using optim(), specifically I need to find the Fréchet mean.

Let's say I have the next coordinates (1,3),(0,2),(1,5),(-3,-9).

I have them in the data.frame "p".

```
p<-data.frame(X=c(1,0,1,-3), Y=c(3,2,5,-9))
```

My code so far is:

```
fn<-function(x)
{
  for (i in 1:(nrow(p)-1))
  {r<- (p[i,1]-p[i,2])^2 + (p[i+1,1]-p[i+1,2])^2}
}

optim (c(1,1) , fn)
```

I picked 1,1 as starting point.

My distance between two points shall be: (x1-y1)^2 + (x2-y2)^2

My code clearly doesn't work, I needed some guidance on how to make optim() minimize my distance function for my points.

(I am a newbie in R/coding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution of the problem:

```
p <- data.frame(X=c(1,0,1,-3), Y=c(3,2,5,-9))
P <- t(as.matrix(p))
# plot(p)

fn <- function(m) sum((P-m)^2)
optim(c(5,5) , fn)
```

It is using the *recycling rule* in `P-m`.
Here is a variant of `fn()`:

```
fn <- function(m) sum((c(p$X-m[1], p$Y-m[2]))^2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure exactly what you're going for here, but this runs:

```
fn <- function(x) {
  x1 <- x[1]
  y1 <- x[2]
  for (i in 1:nrow(p)){
  r<-(x1-y1)^2 + (p[i,1]-p[i,2])^2
  return(r)
  }
}
optim(c(1,1) , fn)
```

Comment: This answer is unfortunately/obviously wrong and I don't know why it has been accepted. As in the original post it mixes the x- and y-coordinates, it does not initialize `r`, and it does not sum up the distances to all the points in `p`. [I would suggest to delete this answer.] BTW, the minimum distance for the example is reached in `c(-0.25, 0.25)`

Comment: `fn <- function(m) sum((p$X-m[1])^2 + (p$Y-m[2])^2)`

Comment: Hi Hans and jogo, I understand the apparent issues with how the problem is set up and mentioned that in my post. I used the formula specified by the OP.